# MaterialDatePicker android selects previous to specified date instead of the specified date

Tags: java, android, materialdatepicker

When I create a `MaterialDatePicker` it picks the previous date of the date I specified, instead of the specified date:

You can see that the EditText has May 12, 2019 but the DatePicker shows as May 11, 2019

[image: You can see that the EditText has May 12, 2019 but the DatePicker shows as May 11, 2019]

Code for the openDatePicker is:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

    String dateText = "May 12, 2019";
    binding.etDate.setText(dateText);
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse(dateText);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        binding.etDate.setTag(cal);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    binding.etDate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Calendar defaultCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (binding.etDate.getTag() != null) {
            defaultCal = (Calendar) binding.etDate.getTag();
        }
        openDatePicker(binding.etDate, defaultCal, createDatePickerConstraints(defaultCal, null, null));
    });
}

private void openDatePicker(final EditText tv, Calendar defaultDate, CalendarConstraints constraints) {
    try {
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraints);
        builder.setSelection(defaultDate.getTimeInMillis());
        MaterialDatePicker<Long> datePicker = builder.build();
        datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(selection -> {
            Calendar selectedCalObj = Calendar.getInstance();
            selectedCalObj.setTimeInMillis((long) selection);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            String date = dateFormat.format(selectedCalObj.getTime())
                    .replace("a.m.", "AM")
                    .replace("p.m.", "PM")
                    .replace("am", "AM")
                    .replace("pm", "PM");;
            tv.setText(date);
            tv.setTag(selectedCalObj);
        });
        datePicker.addOnNegativeButtonClickListener(view -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled");
        });
        datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// helper function to give the constraints:
private CalendarConstraints createDatePickerConstraints(final Calendar entry, final Calendar start, final Calendar end) {
    CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
    if (entry != null)
        constraintsBuilder.setOpenAt(entry.getTimeInMillis());
    if (start != null) {
        constraintsBuilder.setStart(start.getTimeInMillis());
        constraintsBuilder.setValidator(DateValidatorPointForward.from(start.getTimeInMillis()));
    }
    if (end != null) {
        constraintsBuilder.setEnd(end.getTimeInMillis());
        constraintsBuilder.setValidator(DateValidatorPointBackward.before(end.getTimeInMillis()));
    }
    return constraintsBuilder.build();
}
```

Possible way that I know to is to fix by offsetting the `EditText` `binding.etDate.setTag` at `onCreate`  to the current timezone I am in (since the issue is the time being May 12, 2019 0:00:00 that might be the issue of the DatePicker picking the previous date when opened) but it would be really helpful if there is a better way to do this, since this seems like a more common code that will be useful everywhere so that I can make it as a library and just call this as a library code in my main application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can pass with time like **May 12, 2019 01:10:20** because if you passing milliseconds and that one millisecond can differ the day/month/year.

Comment: The Backend just gives me the day and not the time, and I am afraid to do any modifications since if people from other countries use the application they might be having some possible issue with it.

Comment: You should use UTC time.

Comment: Could you share a example/gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after going through loads of GitHub issues, I found that `MaterialDatePicker` has getters and setters only for time in UTC, so offsetting values won't be a good idea so pass in the current time to it as a UTC like: [Link for converting current timezone to UTC](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/00dc4c6b5af3939418f1c7d1e4c737dc3fb7fd67/docs/components/Picker.md#timezones)

My sample code:

```java
try { 
    SimpleDateFormat fromDate = new SimpleDateFromat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    fromDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date = fromDate.parse(inputDateString);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    cal.setTime(date);
    binding.etDate.setTag(cal);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I will be using the tag from the `EditText` later to populate my `CalendarConstraints` and the `MaterialDatePicker`'s `setSelection` later.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`builder.setSelection(defaultDate.getTimeInMillis());`

You have to add offset with current time like this

`builder.setSelection(defaultDate.getTimeInMillis() + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(defaultDate.getTimeInMillis()));`

Comment: This doesn't work as expected because the response from the `datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener` callback is akready offsetted by the current timezone... Maybe I could offset that to `0:00:00` but the whole thing looks like a bad practice. :(